# Passing value in form with amforms plugin

Tags: plugin-amforms

I've created a form using amforms to ask some info about the visitor when he request a document.
I want to pass the name of the requested document in the form.

So I created the field `nomDocumentEfficy` and attached it to my form but I cannot get the value in my submitted forms.

Here is my form :

```
<div class="form-askemail contact">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}

    {# This should always be here! #}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="/amForms/submissions/saveSubmission">

    {# Insert your form's handle. #}
    <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">

    {# This will namespace your inputs (for IDs and such), but it's not required though #}
    <input type="hidden" name="namespace" value="{{ form.getNamespace() }}">

    {# Optional: Redirect URL. Will redirect to current page by default. #}
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.getParam('redirect') }}">

    {# Optional: Anti-spam protection. #}
    {{ craft.amForms.displayAntispam() }}

    {# Optional: Google reCAPTCHA protection. #}
    {{ craft.amForms.displayRecaptcha() }}

    {# Place the HTML of your fields here #}
    {{ form.displayField('email') }}
    {{ form.displayField('societe') }}
    {{ form.displayField('typeEtablissementAskEmailForm') }}
    {{ form.displayField('numeroDepartement') }}

    {# Hidden input field with my value #}
    <input type="hidden" name="nomDocumentEfficy" value="my_value">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you submit forms to Craft, your `name` attribute must be formatted in a certain way by adding your values to a `fields[]` array. In your case, the field should look like:

`<input type="hidden" name="fields[nomDocumentEfficy]" value="my_value">`

You can see this happening if you ever inspect a form field inside an entry in the CMS, or if you inspect the output generated by amforms' tags you're using: `{{ form.displayField('email') }}`

**However**, *not all form field types get added to this array the same as a simple `text` or `hidden` field!* For reference on how to format `checkbox` fields, `date` fields, or even Matrix fields, for example, you can reference this great guide on [StraightUpCraft](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input).